# python watchdog using uwsgi api when file change

Tags: python, uwsgi, python-watchdog

whenever I try out this code and the file updates, I get the following message on the command line:

> SystemError: you can call uwsgi api function only from the main
>   callable

Can anybody explain to me how to do this right?

Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.uwsgi_websocket import WebSocket
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

app = Flask(__name__)
ws = WebSocket(app)

class MyEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, observer, filename, ws):
        self.observer = observer
        self.filename = filename
        self.ws = ws

    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.ws.send('The file is updated!')

@ws.route('/')
def websocket_server(ws):
    path = '/var/lib/omniwallet/addr/'
    observer = Observer()

    while True:
        address = ws.receive()
        if address is not None:
            filename = address + '.json'

            event_handler = MyEventHandler(observer, filename, ws)
            observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)
            observer.start()

            try:
                while True:
                    time.sleep(1)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                observer.stop()
            observer.join()

        else: return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, threads=16)
```

Comment: did you fix it? I have a similar issue. could you share it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use that approach, as the observer runs in another thread, completely unrelated to the one managing the request. You could change the logic using a thread queue: the MyEventHandler write to the queue, while the main callable wait for it and send back a websocket message.